# Why doesn't work the CSS in a Windows Store Template?

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm using the *Grip App* Template and I have made some changes for example because I can't add an Id in the *groupedItems.html*:

```
    <div class="itemtemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div id="item" data-win-bind="className: importancia">
        <img class="item-image" src="#" data-win-bind="src: backgroundImage; alt: title" />
        <div class="item-overlay">
            <h4 class="item-title" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h4>
            <h6 class="item-subtitle win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: subtitle"></h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the *CSS* I've made all changes in *groupedItems.css* for example:

```
    .groupeditemspage .groupeditemslist #item {
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr 90px;
    display: -ms-grid;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

And works good as the regular template in *data.js* I added a new option:

```
        var sampleItems = [
        { group: sampleGroups[0], importancia: "alta", title: "Item Title: 1", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 1", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: lightGray },
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Item Title: 2", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 2", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: darkGray },
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Item Title: 3", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 3", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: mediumGray },
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Item Title: 4", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 4", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: darkGray },
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Item Title: 5", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 5", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: mediumGray }];
```

And I want to change the width of one item, and I added this code in the head:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .alta {
        width: 510px;
    }
</style>
```

I don't know why is not working, it doesn't do anything. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .alta {
        width: 510px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Since you changed `item` to an id (vs. class) it's now more specific than the class (`alta`), so its width setting will take precedence.  Using !important will override that.  By changing `item` to an id, you may inadvertently affect other styling as well, so do double-check that it works ok.  Alternatively, you could add your `importancia` property to all your elements and have it default to "item" and then "alta item" in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend against using `!important`, as it's not teaching you anything but a hackish way to write styles.  The thing you need to understand is the more "specific" you are with a style, the higher precedent that style has.  For example, take the following structure:

```
<div id="my-div" class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Some Content</div>
</div>
```

The following styles would yield red text because it's more "specific":

```
.outer .inner { color: red; }
.inner { color: blue; }
```

The following example would yield green text, as IDs are ALWAYS more specific:

```
#my-div .inner { color: green; }
.outer .inner { color: red; }
.inner { color: blue; }
```

So to answer your question, you have the following style (which is very "specific"):

```
.groupeditemspage .groupeditemslist #item { ... }
```

In order to give a certain #item a different color, you must do the following:

```
.groupeditemspage .groupeditemslist #item.alta { ... }
```

I would also like to take this time to mention that your use of an ID (#item) within a template like this is not proper.  You can only use an ID once... which is why it's called an ID.  If you use something more than once, it's no longer identifying anything.  You should use a class instead.

Comment: Wow, anonymous down-voting troll.  You must be the jerk who put all these `!important` flags on this project I am working on.  Now I am re-writing *your* irresponsible code